# Convert URL to Slug With PHP

Tags: php, jquery, replace

I'm using the below code to try and convert to slug and for some reason it's not echoing anything. I know I'm missing something extremely obvious. Am I not calling the function?

```
<?php 

        $string = "Can't You Convert This To A Slug?";

        function clean($string) {
           $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
           return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
           echo $string;
        }

?>
```

Comment: What's a slug and where's the URL you're covering into a slug?

Comment: @Shahar in `WordPress` parlance the `slug` is the `URL key` of a particular post.

Comment: You're never invoking the method... Add `clean($string);` at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are echoing after the code exit from function.

try like this:

```
 function clean_string($string) {
   $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
   return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
 }

$some = clean_string("Can't You Convert This To A Slug?");

echo $some;
```

Or like this:

```
 function clean_me(&$string) {
   $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
   $string = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
 }

$some = "Can't You Convert This To A Slug?";

clean_me($some);

echo $some;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

        $string = "Can't You Convert This To A Slug?";

        function clean($string) {
           $string = str_replace(' ', '-', $string); // Replaces all spaces with hyphens.
           return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $string); // Removes special chars.
        }

        $string = clean($string);
        echo $string;
?>
```